# "require" doesn't include my file from the parent directory

Tags: php, include, require

I have a tree which looks like this :

[image]

I've been trying to includes file.php from AnotherFile.php :

[image]

I get this error :

[image]

Eventhough my IDE doesn't warn that the file is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In instances like this, it's often better to use somewhat absolute paths instead of relative paths. You can make things easier with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to tell the code to start in your webroot instead of the system's root.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file.php');
```